# Keep Your Head Up

Tags: rebus

[image: keepyourheadup]

Always remember this rule. What is the image above trying to say?

**Hint 1:**

> There is some good ol' slicing; there is some good ol' concatenation; there is some good ol' symbol-to-English. Save the $\pm L_\alpha$ symbol for last; it is the most obscure.

**Hint 2:**

> Focus on manipulating actual letters to construct the whole, left to right. For example, a map of Spain "minus" a picture of a father could be "Sin".

**Hint 3:**

> "Equals to" in plain English must be what? And do zeroes perhaps have look-alikes?

Comment: Those numbers with colons looked like biblical citations to me, but I guess there are no zeroth chapters ...

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) will help with interpreting the colons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Full Answer**

With anodyne's comments on my previous answer, and Lanny Strack's push in the right direction (technically he got the answer first so if he posts I would suggest accepting his), I got:

> The Onleeway (S)out(H) is throo => The only way out is through.

Reasoning:

> With anodyne's comment about slicing, I think 1[0:1] -> On (first two letters of one) and 3[0:2] -> Thr (first three letters of Three). With the second hint, I think the compass and picture yields 'out' (south - sh). The third hint gives me = -> 'is' and "0" to "O" (colloquial way to say zero out loud).

Then with anodyne's comment about

> [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leeway#Definition_of_Leeway_Parameters)

We can get the tricky symbol to be

> leeway

Which ties it all together.

**Previous Partial Answer**

> With anodyne's comment about slicing, I think 1[0:1] -> O (first letter of one) and 3[0:2] -> Th (first two letters of Three). With the second hint, I think the compass and picture yields 'out' (south - sh). The third hint gives me something like = -> 'is' and "0" to "O" (colloquial way to say zero out loud).

So I'm getting something like

> 'The O ? out is thoo' .... which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I think you need to rot13(vapyhqr bar zber yrggre va rnpu bs lbhe fyvprf). The full answer seems like it should be rot13(gur bayl jnl bhg vf guebhtu), but I can't get the  ±Lα part to produce rot13(yljnl).

Comment: @LannyStrack I agree with your suggestions, except the first part  rot13(nppbeqvat gb gur FB yvax gur frpbaq ahzore fubhyq or rkpyhqrq). Regardless on that, I agree that I think your final suggested answer is most likely correct, but I'm stuck right there with you.

Comment: You're so close! As @Lanny Strack says, rot13(mreb:bar zrnaf gur svefg gjb yrggref ol pbairagvba). Finally, there is a word that sounds like that last piece that Lanny says is missing, which, coincidentally, can be represented by ±Lα.

Comment: @anodyne - Is it simply that rot13(Yα pna nyfb or jevggra nf Yl-α, juvpu pbhyq cbffvoyl or cebabhaprq nf "Ylr-N" naq fbhaqf yvxr "yljnl")?

Comment: spoiler [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leeway#Definition_of_Leeway_Parameters) only because the puzzle is basically solved at this point

Comment: @anodyne or is it trying to get to rot13(yrrjnl)?

Comment: @PartyHatPanda - you did the heavy lifting, so you can claim the answer.

Comment: @LannyStrack I'll leave it to anodyne, but I did call out you getting the answer before me in my own answer, so I won't feel bad if you put in your answer!

Comment: @PartyHatPanda - I am not going to post an answer. I didn't solve enough of it to feel justified doing that.